# Regular expression for mobile number vaidation?

Tags: java, regex

I have following regular expression for following mobile numbers:

```
^(([+]|[0]{2})([\\d]{1,3})([\\s-]{0,1}))?([\\d]{10})$
```

Valid numbers are:

```
+123-9854875847
00123 9854875847
+123 9854875847
9878757845
```

Above expression will not validate if user enter 9 or 11 digit mobile number but if user enter 9 or 11 digit number with `+123` or `+91` respectively then it is getting validate because in this part of expression `([\\d]{1,3})` last two digits are optional.

So, any way to make this part `([\\s-]{0,1}))?([\\d]{10})` not to get combine with this part `([\\d]{1,3})`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is somewhat unclear, but I presume you want to split the number and the country code.

This is quite easy to do by extracting groups. `group(i)` is the `i`-th thing in brackets.

I also applied these simplifications: `[\\d]` = `\\d`, `{0,1}` = `?`, `[+]` = `\\+`, `[0]{2}` = `00`.

**Code:**

```
String regex = "^((\\+|00)(\\d{1,3})[\\s-]?)?(\\d{10})$";
String str = "+123-9854875847";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.matches())
{
   System.out.println("Country = " + m.group(3));
   System.out.println("Data = " + m.group(4));
}
```

**Output:**

```
Country = 123
Data = 9854875847
```

**Alternative using non-matching groups (`?:`):** (so you can use `group(1)` and `group(2)`)

```
String regex = "^(?:(?:\\+|00)(\\d{1,3})[\\s-]?)?(\\d{10})$";
String str = "+123-9854875847";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.matches())
{
   System.out.println("Country = " + m.group(1));
   System.out.println("Data = " + m.group(2));
}
```

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

[Related test](https://ideone.com/fhCrpu).

Answer (score 1):

As long as the extension is always separated from the rest of the phone number, your regex will work fine. If there is no such separation, there is no way to correctly validate a phone number.

Also keep in mind that both extensions and phone numbers can vary in length from country to country, so there is no regex that will solve all cases. If you can produce a list of allowed extensions, you can work that into the regex and get better matches, but for many groups of arbitrary length of digits you will get many wrong matches.

I have simplified your regex a bit, so oyu can see @Dukeling's suggestions in practice. Your regex on top, mine on the bottom.

```
^(([+]|[0]{2})([\\d]{1,3})([\\s-]{0,1}))?([\\d]{10})$
^(  (\\+|00)    \\d{1,3}    [\\s-]?)?      \\d{10}  $
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try {


            String mobile_number="india number +919979045000\n" +
                    "india number 9979045000\n" +
                    "china number +86 591 2123654\n" +
                    "Brazil number +55 79 2012345\n" +
                    "it is test all string get mobile number all country"+
                    "Ezipt +20 10 1234567\n" +
                    "France +33 123456789\n" +
                    "Hong Kong  +852 1234 5456\n" +
                    "Mexico +52 55 12345678"+
                    "thanks";

            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\(?\\+[0-9]{1,3}\\)? ?-?[0-9]{1,3} ?-?[0-9]{3,5} ?-?[0-9]{5}( ?-?[0-9]{3})? ?(\\w{1,10}\\s?\\d{1,6})?");
            List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
            //mobile_number= mobile_number.replaceAll("\\-", "");
            Matcher m = p.matcher("" + mobile_number);
            while (m.find()) {
                numbers.add(m.group());
            }

            p = Pattern.compile("\\(?\\+[0-9]{1,3}\\)? ?-?[0-9]{1,3} ?-?[0-9]{3,5} ?-?[0-9]{4}( ?-?[0-9]{3})? ?(\\w{1,10}\\s?\\d{1,6})?");
            m = p.matcher("" + mobile_number);
            while (m.find()) {
                numbers.add(m.group());
            }

            p = Pattern.compile("((?:|\\+)([0-9]{5})(?: |\\-)(0\\d|\\([0-9]{5}\\)|[1-9]{0,5}))");
            m = p.matcher("" + mobile_number);
            while (m.find()) {
                numbers.add(m.group());
            }

            p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{10}|\\(?\\+[0-9]{1,3}\\)?-?[0-9]{3,5} ?-?[0-9]{4}?");
            m = p.matcher("" + mobile_number);
            while (m.find()) {
                numbers.add(m.group());
            }

            String numberArray=numbers.toString();
            System.out.print(""+numberArray);

            // final result 
            /* [+919979045000, +86 591 2123654, +33 123456789, +52 55 12345678, +919979045000, +86 591 2123654, +55 79 2012345, +20 10 1234567, +33 123456789, +852 1234 5456, +52 55 12345678, +919979045000, 9979045000] */


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to take input in two parts i.e country code and mobile number.
In that case you can easily validate it (both country code and mobile number) with regex.